# How can I execute a block of code on two iOS devices with nanosecond precision?

Tags: ios, synchronization, multipeer-connectivity

I'm trying to perform two actions in perfect sync on multiple connected iOS devices.

For example, I'd like to execute a block of code at X date, where X is a date defined with nanoseconds accuracy. I'd like execution to take place on all devices.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered the same problem and developed a lightweight manager called `Synaction` which can be found [here](https://github.com/ge0rges/synaction). Synaction takes care of calculating the offset between devices and the host, and then will also cover executing the block of code within nanoseconds precision as provided.

It's bundled with a MultipeerConnectivity manager class which it leverages to communicate with networked devices with whom it needs to sync.

What's left for you is to handle sending the "commands" to trigger sync, specifying the time you want it synced, and what should be executed.